# Show an already imported project in Eclipse package explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, import, project

I was importing in Eclipse an android application project, but i forgot to check the voice "Copy into workspace". When i try to re-import this project, the wizard shows me the error "Cannot import ProjectName because the project name is in use".

Seems like Eclipse recognizes a project in the workspace, but it doesn't show it in the package explorer. How can i fix it? Thanks.